# Can I pull images from a category with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

What is the best way to pull videos or images that are categorized?

Is it possible to write in values into an array ie: landscape, technology, abstract, etc.. 
And then when the user selects an input they are given the items that fall into the category or would I need to use PHP or JSON to write something like this effectively?

What I am trying to do is have a page that will randomize images/videos from an array. 
The user when visiting the page will be able to select a category from a dropdown and the randomizer will only randomize images with that category tag and display them one at a time.

If no category is selected then it will randomize from the total amount of videos.

the code I currently have is set for videos but images/videos is the same concept

```
    <head>
        <title>Randomizer</title>
    </head>

    <body> 

         <section>

          <div class="desktop">
            <video loop autoplay>

              <source src="" type="">
              <source src="" type="">
              Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
            </video>
          </div> 

        </section>

    </body>

</html>
```

JavaScript

```
var videos = [
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'/videos/1.webm'}, {type:'webm', 'src':'/videos/1.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'/videos/2.webm'}, {type:'webm', 'src':'/videos/2.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'/videos/3.webm'}, {type:'webm', 'src':'/videos/3.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'/videos/4.webm'}, {type:'webm', 'src':'/videos/4.mp4'}],
    [{type:'mp4', 'src':'/videos/5.webm'}, {type:'webm', 'src':'/videos/5.mp4'}], 

];



$(function() {
    $('section').on('click', 'div', function(e) {
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*videos.length);
    $(this).find('source').each(function(index){ 
          videoSrc = videos[number][index].src;
          $(this).attr('src', videoSrc);
          $('video').load();
          $('video').play();
        });
    });
}); 


$(document).ready(function() { 
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*videos.length); 
     $(this).find('source').each(function(index){ 
          videoSrc = videos[number][index].src;
          $(this).attr('src', videoSrc);
          $('video').load();
          $('video').play();
        });
     }
);
```

Any help or insight is much appreciated! Thanks everyone!

Comment: Remove `.on()` from the closure and add it to `$(document).ready`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the task correctly, what you are trying to achieve is something like this:

1. `videos` json array

```js
var videos = [
    { category: 'landscape',  sources: [ { type: 'webm', src: '/videos/1.webm'  }, { type: 'mp4', src: '/videos/1.mp4' } ] },
    { category: 'landscape',  sources: [ { type: 'webm', src: '/videos/2.webm'  }, { type: 'mp4', src: '/videos/2.mp4' } ] },
    { category: 'landscape',  sources: [ { type: 'webm', src: '/videos/3.webm'  }, { type: 'mp4', src: '/videos/3.mp4' } ] },
    { category: 'technology', sources: [ { type: 'webm', src: '/videos/4.webm'  }, { type: 'mp4', src: '/videos/4.mp4' } ] },
    { category: 'technology', sources: [ { type: 'webm', src: '/videos/5.webm'  }, { type: 'mp4', src: '/videos/5.mp4' } ] },
    { category: 'technology', sources: [ { type: 'webm', src: '/videos/6.webm'  }, { type: 'mp4', src: '/videos/6.mp4' } ] },
    { category: 'abstract',   sources: [ { type: 'webm', src: '/videos/7.webm'  }, { type: 'mp4', src: '/videos/7.mp4' } ] },
    { category: 'abstract',   sources: [ { type: 'webm', src: '/videos/8.webm'  }, { type: 'mp4', src: '/videos/8.mp4' } ] },
    { category: 'abstract',   sources: [ { type: 'webm', src: '/videos/9.webm'  }, { type: 'mp4', src: '/videos/9.mp4' } ] },
    { category: 'abstract',   sources: [ { type: 'webm', src: '/videos/10.webm' }, { type: 'mp4', src: '/videos/10.mp4'} ] },
    { category: 'abstract',   sources: [ { type: 'webm', src: '/videos/11.webm' }, { type: 'mp4', src: '/videos/11.mp4'} ] }
];
```

2. this array is going to be filtered by category

```js
var category = 'technology'; // take the category from dropdown
var videosByCategory = videos.filter(function(video) {
    return video.category === category;
});
```

3. then use some shuffling algorithm, like the one from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/3819736

```js
function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

        // Pick a remaining element...
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;

        // And swap it with the current element.
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
}
```

4. and the final condition

```js
var shuffledVideos = shuffle(videosByCategory.length > 0 ? videosByCategory : videos);
```

5. [Pluker](http://plnkr.co/HCb1LWVvJDvfZRgad2zR)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the reply sbedulin. 
There is one thing I am unsure about. How would the HTML look on this? Also, would I just replace all of my current javascript with the code you've shown and it would work ? Or would I have to keep my current javascript for the on click and onload randomize functions?

Comment: @h0bb5 welcome! I added working plunk to the answer - please have a look. Although I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with videos in the displayed list.

Comment: Ah awesome! that's almost perfect!
Yeah what i'm trying to achieve is just to have one of the resulting videos or images display at random and then on click it will randomize from that selected category. 

What changes can I make to achieve this? 

Thanks for the help and I will be sure up vote you!

Comment: @h0bb5, thanks! I updated the plunk, you can use any html template in video view, e.g. play the video once it's selected. I don't understand `click` part though - one more random needed? :)

Comment: Yes!!! Just one more randomize is needed for the click part. 
So basically the div or section would be wrapped in an <a href="#" class="click"> tag and once that section is clicked a randomize would occur but only from within the category that is selected :) 
Thanks heaps for your help! Once that is finished that will be absolutely everything I was having trouble with

Comment: One more thing, I also noticed that it's outputting the randomized result as 'Webm: /videos/3.webm; Mp4: /videos/3.mp4' 
With the code I had written earlier I had it so that when it would randomize it would output the 'src' and 'type' into a video tag like this <source src="" type="">. So the results would output into the empty spaces in the tag. When I try this with your code I am getting undefined :S Thanks again!

Comment: Awesome! That looks pretty much perfect. Thanks tons for your help, i'm going to go through this like crazy to learn what you did. One thing, I have two different file types playing, .webm and .mp4, in your code only one is loaded in, where does the other one go? There needs to be a fallback for browswer compatibillity as safari doesn't support .webm and vice versa with other browsers. If you see my code I have <video src=""> tags one for .mp4 and .webm, how can I have them inject into both?

Comment: @h0bb5 to be honest I don't have a quick answer for `mp4/webm` compatibility, I'd suggest creating a simple page with single `<video>` tag and playing around with supported formats. Such a `<video>` sample can be easily embedded into the current plunk. I'm almost sure `mp4` is supported in every modern browser, but I need to check on this.

Comment: The question wasn't so much about compatibility. More so just how to display the array or data into both tags like my initial code that I began with? where the first one will be .webm and the next will be .mp4

Comment: @h0bb5 I think I got what you mean. I updated plunk and `json` array so that available `<source>` tags, e.g. `<source src="/videos/2.webm" type="webm">`, will now be added to `<video>`. `<video>` is randomized either by category update or by a link click. Escaped html is just a label to show what `<video>` contains at the moment.